# ExpandableListView animation for a child Android

Tags: android, animation, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to apply some kind of an animation for the `ExpandableListView`. I have done some research and looks like its a right pain. I managed to apply slide animation on the expand, however i cant work out how to apply anything on collapse.

I used

[How to write custom ExpandableListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188196/how-to-write-custom-expandablelistadapter)

for my `ExpandableListView`. As it stands at the moment i apply this t oa child `convertView` and it works fine on expand, but i cant figure out how it collapses.

```
 Animation fadeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_left_in);
 convertView.startAnimation(fadeAnimation );
```

Would anyone be able to help or perhaps there is a better solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a nice implementation that extends an ExpandableListView here:
https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView/

It uses the idea I explained here [Android ExpandableListView using animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627113/android-expandablelistview-using-animation) to do the animations.

Answer (score 0):

i do something similar with my `ExpandableListView`.
I use custom child layouts inflated from xml. But this should not matter. 
You should override the `onChildClick` `onGroupClick` and maybe other listeners. In this listeners you can animate your stuff.
And you can try to use `animateLayoutChanges` what was not working fine for me.