# Custom ExpandableListview Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image]

Is there a way in android to create a expandable view as in image? I tried using Expandable ListView ,but it is not upto the mark as required. Kindly provide if this can be done android ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question, "create an expandable view as in image?"  Do you mean, can I create this pictured UI with an ExpandableListView?

Comment: Yes , I am looking to for the same.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is: Don't use expandable list adapter.

Your collection doesn't look like having sub collections(at least less then scrollable amount).Your rows just hide/show details of your data by expanding collapsing.

use a custom  ListAdapter and make each item expand and show detail on  a button click with an Animation (you can find height animation by googling).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I believe it as a perfect solution, if the above stated case is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using custom ExpandableListAdapter.
You can have a look on the following liks
[How to write custom ExpandableListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188196/how-to-write-custom-expandablelistadapter)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more like RecyclerView. At least, i would use it in this case. The main reason is `ViewHolder`. Of course you can provide your own viewholder pattern implementaion, but `RecyclerView` forces you to use `ViewHolder` and provides stubs.

As far as i understand, you don't need to handle click on entire element, but you need to handle click on plus/minus button. So when you implement `ViewHolder`, simply add click listener for that view and show/hide content, like this:

```
class ChartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView storeTitle;
    private ToggleButton toggleBtn;
    // other views

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        storeTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_id);
        toggleBtn = (ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggle_id);
        // other views

        toggleBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked) {
                    // make content visible
                } else {
                    // make conent invisible
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you need animation for expanding/collapsing you should look into [Property animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you should create a custom `ExpandableListAdapter` which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. There are lots of tutorials. Check part 15 of [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial for example.

Answer (score 0):

for expandable listview i have to used below library and its works like charm for me.

https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView